# how to make curl requests to app protected by AzureAD oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an app which is protected by azureAD app registration. everytime user hits an URL, say, https://myapp.com/listall in browser they are presented with azure login screen. This is working as expected.

I was wondering how can I make curl requests to these endpoints from my terminal. When I try it now I get 302 NOT FOUND, as my request is getting redirected to login screen. when I try this form postman I see browser(HTML, CSS) code for azures login screen.

I am expecting something like.

- make a curl request to obtain a token.
- Use this token to subsequent curl requests.

I am making this curl request to get a token

```
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --data \
  "
    grant_type=client_credentials&
    client_id=<client-id>&
    client_secret=<client-secret>&
    resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F
  "
```

I get a token back and then I make request something like this.

```
curl -X GET "https://myapp.com/listall" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1....."
```

am I on the right path? how can I achieve this so that I can make curl requests to apps protected by azure AD app registration ?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the access token successfully.***

Please **note** that the resource URL you are using is for **classic** deployed resources and *`https://management.core.windows.net/`* corresponds to **Azure Service Management API** which is now changed to **`https://management.azure.com/`**

**To get the access token, I made CURL request like below:**

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id/oauth2/token\
-d 'client_id=your_app_client_id' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
-d 'resource=https://management.azure.com/' \
-d 'client_secret=*******************'
```

To call the above **CURL request** in Postman, please follow below steps:

***Run Postman -> Import -> Select Raw Text -> Copy the above CURL request and paste in raw text field -> Continue -> Import -> Send.***

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

After getting the token, I made **API call** like below:

```
curl -X GET "Your_API_Call_http_link" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS....."
```

[image]

Make sure to grant **[API permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdwMw.png)** for your API before calling it in Postman. Ensure to select access tokens and id tokens **[check boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABD80.png)** for your Azure AD app.

Comment: Thanks for the response @SrideviMachavarapu-MT, I can issue a token like you said. But I still get a 302 redirect on my curl command.

Comment: Can you include error snapshot and curl command details to know where exactly you are getting error??

Comment: I am not getting any errors per se, It's just redirecting to login page even when token is passed in header.