# Is there a way to validate azure app credentials?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Given I have the following info from Azure app registration:

Application (client) ID,
Client secret,
Directory (tenant) ID,
Object ID

Is there a way to check it's a valid credential programmatically (like using curl etc but not powershell)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to check client secret validity or even the properties of that app ,then please check if the below c# code can be worked around .We can try to query the application and see expiry date of secret. Please grant the app with `Directory.Read.All` ,Application.Read.All permission to this API for using client credentials flow.

```
var graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
var applicationId= "";
var ObjectId = "";
var clientsecret = "";
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(applicationId,secret);
var tenantId = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");

//get accesstoken
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientCredential).Result.AccessToken;

Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

var app = activeDirectoryClient.Applications.GetByObjectId(appObjectId).ExecuteAsync().Result;

foreach (var passwordCredential in app.PasswordCredentials)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"KeyID:{passwordCredential.KeyId}\r\nEndDate:{passwordCredential.EndDate}\r\n");
}
```

If you want , you can even request token using curl [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72350038/how-to-make-curl-requests-to-app-protected-by-azuread-oauth2) and validate using post man or by checking token in https://jwt.io .

Reference: [check client secret expiry using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075464/how-can-i-tell-when-a-azure-ad-client-secret-expires)